# TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I know this has been asked in many questions, but the most common answer that jQuery isn't loaded doesn't work for me. It seems my jQuery is being loaded properly (version 1.10.2).
I am trying to run the following code (tried even in console, so the loading issue doesn't remain):
`$('.carousel').on('mouseenter',function(){ $( this ).carousel();})`

Bootstrap carousel by itself is working fine. It's just when am trying to initialize it dynamically, it's not working. (I just started with angular and bootstrap, so I might be missing something very simple here.)
I am using angular js and bootstrap for my application.

EDIT:
Here's my html code:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ItemGallery" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <div class="col-md-4 item_card" ng-repeat="item in item_array">
        <a href="{{'/product/id='+item.product_id}}" class="thumbnail">
            <div id="{{'carousel_'+item.product_id}}" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="{{item.thumbnail}}" alt="{{item.product_title}}" class="img-responsive product-image"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="{{item.nutrition_thumbnail}}" alt="{{item.product_title}}" class="img-responsive nutri-image"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="caption post-content">
                <h4 class="h_no_margin">
                    <p class="pull-left title">{{item.product_title.toLowerCase() }}</p>
                    <p class="text-right">${{item.price}}</p>
                </h4>
                <small>
                    {{item.product_desc}}
                </small>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('item_gallery', []);

app.controller('ItemGallery', function($http, $scope, $location) {
$http.get("/product/list")
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.item_array = response.response;
    });


});
```

I used bower to take care of dependencies.

```
{
 "name": "nutrinext",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "dependencies": {
  "angular": "~1.3.1",
  "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.2",
  "angular-timeago": "~0.1.3",
  "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.11",
  "ngstorage": "~0.3.0",
  "bootstrap": "~3.3.0",
  "bootstrap-markdown": "~2.7.0",
  "jquery": "1.10.2",
  "fastclick": "~1.0.3",
  "fontawesome": "~4.2.0",
  "pubnub": "~3.6.4"
 },
"devDependencies": {},
"resolutions": {
  "angular": "~1.3.1",
  "bootstrap": "~3.3.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Seeing your JS code here would help a lot.

Comment: If jQuery wasn't loaded, then would be throwing a reference error on `$`. It says that `carousel` is not a function. Where did you define `carousel`?

Comment: What is in your browser console, any errors? Have you loaded jQuery BEFORE you load the Bootstrap js file?

Comment: .carousel is not a function! use `$(this).slick();` [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: share angularjs code

Comment: @slick Can you explain ? I don't understand... carousel is a function : [here is the doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage)

Comment: @Quentin I thought that `carousel` is defined in bootstrap.js.

Comment: You should be able to find your answer here: [How to use jQuery in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

Comment: The problem was that the dependency wasn't properly done, ui.bootstrap.carousel was missing.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, What I was missing was including `bootstrap.js` in my `index.html`, and after adding following it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set Your script in the bottom of html body.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!--JQUERY-->
      <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!--Boostrap carousel-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
   <!--YOUR CAROUSEL BODY HERE-->
   <h1>Look on the code example</h1>
   </body>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 550 * 10
         });
      });
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the order of the  tags which has the materialize.js, it worked for me!

Specifically, you should maintain this order of the scripts in the source code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

and not the other way around.

Comment: Changing it how? What did it look like before, and what does it look like now? Please [edit] your answer to add more details.

Comment: Try maintaining this order of the scripts in the source code `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`

Comment: and not the other way around!