# AngularJS Directive accessing controler scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

**TL;DR** I solved my problem. Here is plunker with 3 different solutions:

http://plnkr.co/edit/E0ErKs?p=preview

I don`t like slider1 because it stores value in $scope ( {{sliderValue}} ) and according to recommendation from Angular Style Guide we should avoid that.

I don`t like slider2 because it assumes that controler have alias vm in a view (so we create some kind of coupling between view and directive).

Solution 3 looks OK for me. Am I missing something?

How would you write differently this directive to be in complience with Angular philosophy?

---

**INITIAL QUESTION:**

I am learning angular and not everything is clear to me yet.

I found this question:
[How to use jQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

So I created working example:

Directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('demoApp').directive('slider', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.onSlide = function (e, ui) {
                    $scope.sliderValue = ui.value;
                    $scope.$digest();
                };
            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                var options = {
                    value: scope.sliderValue,
                    slide: scope.onSlide  
                };

                // set up slider on load
                angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                    scope.$slider = $(el).slider(options);
                });
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('demoApp').controller('DemoAppTestCtrl', DemoAppTestCtrl);

    DemoAppTestCtrl.$inject = [ '$scope' ];

    function DemoAppTestCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.sliderValue = 10;
    }
})();
```

And Html page:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoAppTestCtrl as vm">
    Value: {{sliderValue}}
    <div slider></div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine. Angular put slider in place of <div slider> and I can move it and I see changing values in {{sliderValue}}.

Then I found this Angular Style Guide
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

In chapter about controllers they recommend to use controllerAs with vm syntax (because $scope is bad or something).

Ex:

```
function CustomerController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = {};
    vm.sendMessage = function() { };
}
```

So I changed my controller to this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('demoApp').controller('DemoAppTestCtrl', DemoAppTestCtrl);

    DemoAppTestCtrl.$inject = [ ];

    function DemoAppTestCtrl($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.sliderValue = 10;
    }
})();
```

And Html page to:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoAppTestCtrl as vm">
    Value: {{vm.sliderValue}}
    <div slider></div>
</div>
```

But i don`t know how to fix my directive. 
I want the same functionality, when i move the slider i want to set vm.sliderValue inside controler instead $scope.sliderValue inside scope.

**EDIT1:**

I was able to make it work by adding $scope.vm inside controller and link functions (because my controller sits in scope as vm). But I am not sure if this is right way to do it, because now my directive assume that there is controller in scope under $scope.vm alias.

Is this bad design or normal way of doing things in Angular ?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('demoApp')
        .directive('slider', slider);

    slider.$inject = [ ];

    function slider() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.vm.onSlide = function (e, ui) {
                    $scope.vm.sliderValue = ui.value;
                    $scope.$digest();
                };
            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
               var options = {
                   value: scope.vm.sliderValue,
                   slide: scope.vm.onSlide  
               };

               // set up slider on load
               angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                   scope.$slider = $(el).slider(options);
               });
            }
         }
    }
})();
```

**EDIT2:**

I was able to create working Plunker with 3 different versions:
http://plnkr.co/edit/E0ErKs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use scope: false as a option in the directive.

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: But as I understand the scope: false causes that  directive uses its parent scope. But i dont use $scope in my new version of controller. Instead I am storing sliderValue inside Controller (not in scope). So my question is how to set value inside this controller from directive (since this is now recommended way of writing controllers).

Comment: Do like this: <div slider="vm.sliderValue"></div> and then in the link function you can access this variable in attrs.slider

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('DemoAppTestCtrl', DemoAppTestCtrl);

function DemoAppTestCtrl() {
 var vm = this;
 
  vm.sliderValue = 10;
}

angular.module('myApp').directive('slider', sliderDirective );

function sliderDirective() {
 return {
   restrict: 'A',
    controller: sliderController,
    controllerAs: 'sliderCtrl',
    template: "<p>{{sliderCtrl.test}}</p>"
  }
}

function sliderController() {
 var vm = this;
  
  vm.test = "hello";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="DemoAppTestCtrl as vm">
    Value: {{vm.sliderValue}}
    <div slider></div>
</div>
</div>
```