# JQuery not recognized in Angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, load

I'm trying to use JQuery inside Angular and I just can't seem to make it work. This is how my **index.html** file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controller1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So after I loaded all those scripts, I'm thinking I can start using **$** inside app.js or inside any other .js file I make, but it won't recognize it. The warning says "*$ is not defined; please fix or add global $*". How can I use JQuery inside a .js file?

Comment: load jQuery before angular when you want to let angular use it internally for `angular.element`

Comment: Also note you have a mismatch of angular version numbers

Comment: Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion would be moving the `<script>` and `<link>` tags that load jQuery to the top. The script tags are executed from top to bottom, so any script that depends on another script must be loaded after it.

Additionally, there is another SO question that deals with a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)