# use jquery in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to apply jquery's wrapIn() function to data imported through angularjs scopes. From other questions I've read here (such as [How to use jQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)) I need to put it in a directive, but I'm not familiar with it, and my code doesn't work.

Here's what I tried to write for a scope

```
$scope.wrapInTag = function () {
  $.fn.wrapInTag = function(opts) {
    var tag = opts.tag || 'strong',
    words = opts.words || [],
    regex = RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi'),
    replacement = '<'+ tag +'>$&</'+ tag +'>';
    return this.html(function() {
     return $(this).html().replace(regex, replacement);
   });
  };
  $('p').wrapInTag({
    tag: 'u',
    words: ['green']
  });
};
```

I basically just put the original js function inside a $scope, I must be missing something. Thanks!

EDIT
This is my scope for the data

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.things = [
    {
      name: 'thing1',
      colour1: 'blue',
      colour2: 'yellow', 
      colour2: 'green'
    },{
      name: 'thing2',
      colour1: 'green',
      colour2: 'orange',
      colour3: 'red'
    }
  ];
});
```

And this is how I call the data

```
<div>
<ul ng-repeat="thing in things">
<li>{{ thing.name }}{{ thing.colour1 }}, {{ thing.colour2 }}, {{ thing.colour3 }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With the goal being to have the word 'green' underlined.

Comment: Could do this also as a custom filter or parse your data before passing to view. Are you using `ng-bind-html` to insert this? Also are you using jQuery only for this, or using jQuery at all? Shouldn't need it just for this

Comment: Show how you are trying to invoke `$scope.wrapInTag()`. More feedback on how you plan to use this will help

Comment: You could also avoid using `jquery` and use the Angular good parts, like defining a directive and `$compile` the template content dynamically

Comment: I'm not using any other ng for this. I just realized that the way I went about was most probably wrong, as this scope is supposed to apply to also another scope which is data? I'm not entirely sure how to use directives, nor how to $compile, but maybe I should look into this last option? I kept on looking, and found about the 'angular.element(element);' function, it seems like it could be quite direct https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element (also, sorry for the delay, I kep on looking to see if I had answers but there are no notifications for comments...)