# How to load Scripts async with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

As I have some bad experiences with the mix of Angular and jQuery, I am trying to avoid jQuery in Angular. Right now, I should add some code to my Angular project but I am not sure how I should convert this. The code is coming from someone else who wants me to implement this in the project.

Within my project I have added all of the required libraries into the index.html. I think this is the only place where a library can be added.

Does someone know (if there is a way) how I can convert those jquery code lines into Angular or javascript code? Where in the project should I add this?

```
$('head').append( '<meta name="PAGENAME" content="$pagename">' );

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getScript( "https://www.website.com/crsc/scripts/script.js" )
      .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        console.log( 'loaded test' );
      })

      .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
               console.log('not loaded');     
      });

});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to load a script in angular? If so you should update the question title.

Comment: you can add a script tag in your index file with async=true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

Comment: @DanteTheSmith OP is **not** trying to use jQuery with Angular but rather the opposite, avoid using jQuery.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting downvoted, it was a good question to me.

Comment: I think the question was not formed the right way. Because I'm a bit desperate for a solution, I didn't take a lot of time for the formulation. I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `app.run` which will run like a `main method` before the app loads everything

```
     app.run(["scriptService"],function(scriptService){
        scriptService.GetScripts()
          .then(function(success){console.log("loaded test");},
         function(error){ console.log("not loaded");}
    }]);
```

Next all you have to do is make a script Service.

```
    app.factory("scriptService", ["$http", function ($http) {
                this.GetScripts = function ()
    { 
return $http.get(""https://www.website.com/crsc/scripts/script.js") .then(function(result) { return result});

    }
```

**but in reality why do you not  just import the script through a script tag**?
Loading a script async, since op didnt know that was an option I thought I would include it here [ww3 schools async loading](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_script_async.asp)

```
  <script src="demo_async.js" async></script>
```

> definition and Usage The async attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that the script will be executed
>   asynchronously as soon as it is available.
>
> Note: The async attribute is only for external scripts (and should
>   only be used if the src attribute is present).
>
> Note: There are several ways an external script can be executed:
>
> If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the
>   rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues
>   the parsing) If async is not present and defer is present: The script
>   is executed when the page has finished parsing If neither async or
>   defer is present: The script is fetched and executed immediately,
>   before the browser continues parsing the page Browser Support The
>   numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully
>   supports the attribute.

Comment: exactly a simple script with async load should be enough .

Comment: I thought so too, but i figured op had his/her reasons

Comment: I didn't know async loading would give me the same result, thanks