# Angular 2: jquery's getScript vs. HttpClient get + eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

We have an Angular 2 Project, where we try not to have any jquery dependency. BUT, we somehow have to load a script and run that. Until now this is the only place where we used jquery's getScript.

What if we use Angular's HttpClient's 'get' with an eval(script)? Is there then any advantages or disadvantages compared to jquery's getScript?

Comment: This could maybe be a duplicate, anyway, your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204417/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-from-angular-component/44276683#44276683

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load external javascript file from Angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204417/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-from-angular-component)

Comment: You write javascript or jquery in angularjs controller [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

Comment: I dont ask here how to do it. I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of both worlds. So is not a duplicate