# $(document).ready() is not working sometimes in AngularJS app

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a directive which has a `templateUrl`. In the directive, there is a $scope variable initialized as

```
$scope.mapLoaded = false;
```

and a method

```
$scope.onMapLoaded = function(){
    $scope.mapLoaded = true;
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

In the `$scope.init()` function, I am checking that, if the map is loaded, the call a method `initAutocomplete()` (This method initialize the google address API)

```
        $scope.init = function()
        {
            console.log('init() is called ' + ' at '+ Date.now());
            if($scope.applicationId === undefined || $scope.applicationId == '') return false;
            $scope.getAssetLocations($scope.loadAssetLocations);
            $scope.getAccountId($scope.loadAccountId);
            if($scope.mapLoaded === true){
                console.log('[$scope.init] >Map loaded is '+ $scope.mapLoaded + ' at '+ Date.now());
                $timeout( function(){
                    $scope.initAutocomplete();
                    }, 4000 );
           }
        };
```

I am also watching the `$scope.mapLoaded` variable

```
           $scope.$watch('mapLoaded', function () {
            console.log('[$watch(mapLoaded)] >Map loaded is '+ $scope.mapLoaded + ' at '+ Date.now());
            if($scope.mapLoaded === true){
                 $timeout( function(){
                     $scope.initAutocomplete();
                     }, 4000 );
            }
         });
```

And in the view part, I am checking via jQuery that, if the document is ready, then load the google map.

```
<html>
..some html here
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('loadGoogleMap is called from ApplicationAsset at '+ Date.now() + ' after the document is ready');
        window.setTimeout(loadGoogleMap, 1000);

    });

    function loadGoogleMap(){
        if (window.google && document.getElementById('AppAssetLocation')) {
            angular.element(document.getElementById('AppAssetLocation')).scope().onMapLoaded(); 
            console.log('loadGoogleMap called from ApplicationAsset at '+ Date.now());
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(loadGoogleMap, 1000);
            console.log('Again, loadGoogleMap is trying to call from ApplicationAsset at '+ Date.now());
        }
    }

</script>
```

But, what happens here, sometimes it calls `window.setTimeout(loadGoogleMap, 1000);` inside `$(document).ready` and sometimes it is not calling. And it is completely random.

What's the problem here folks?

Comment: What is not calling? The `setTimeout`? Or `loadGoogleMap` within the timeout? You also have a potential endless loop there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

Comment: Sometimes it is not printing the console.log() message. How an infinite loop can occur there?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney How an infinite loop can occur there?

Comment: In `loadGoogleMap`, if the first `if` is never satisfied it will go to `else`, which then restarts the function and will do the same again and again and...

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {// Code here});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () { // Code here });
```

and that solved my problem.