# How to use jQuery Date Time Range picker in ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Angular and ionic.
I am using ionic v3 and want date time picker plugin in my app. I found this one.
http://www.daterangepicker.com/

But this is jQuery plugin, but my app is on Angular and ionic so how can I use jQuery with Angular.

I found this solution.

[How to use jQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666289/how-to-use-jquery-in-angularjs)

Still not getting how to do this for me.

Thank you

Comment: What are the errors you are facing? also, you are referring to the question of AngularJs not Angular, both are different.

Comment: I din't knew about the diff between AngularJs and Angular but I searched the web so I came to know that I am working on Angular coz its typescript based and I am not able to make the code , I am not facing any errors as I am new to angular ionic so I am not able to write or understand how to combine this jQuery plugin with angular to work in ionic app

Comment: So I would suggest you to first understand the basic concepts about Angular, how things will work, how third party lib. works with angular etc.

Comment: okay thank you ... any link where I could learn this from

Comment: Better is Documentation but it's too lengthy. Or you just google it you will find number of articles

Comment: @NeerajWalia Which angular version you are using? In ionic may be you are using angular 5+.

Comment: Thank you it worked like a simple jQuery ... and angular version I don't know how to check that .... but thank you